# NoMethodError in undefined method `scoped' in rails (using ancestry gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the ancestry gem and i m testing my model in the console first.When i use

```
  root = Message.create(:content => "hello")
```

It inserts data into the database but when i use

```
  child = root.children.create(:content => "hhjjh")
```

It gives an error.This is the log

```
  NoMethodError: undefined method `scoped' for #<Class:0x007fa4a61182b0>
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/ancestry-1.2.3/lib/ancestry/instance_methods.rb:136:in `children'
from (irb):2
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/zeeshandar/chat/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/zeeshandar/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I don't know what i m doing wrong but i think this is suppose to work.Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your version of Ancestry is 1.2.3 or something. Updating to a new version looks like it should fix that problem.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'ancestry', '~> 2.1'
```